# Incompatible operand types in object within object

Tags: java, class, object, types, casting

first question here.. I have a simple program with separate classes (student, faculty, book, classroom) where you can search by name, e price, room capacity, etc. These objects are all stored in a Bag class. I have a separate Object class as well to extend the student, faculty, etc classes. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the casting in the main Bag class. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package Bag;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    private static ArrayList<Object> collection = new ArrayList();

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("Sameet", 1, 4);
        Faculty faculty = new Faculty("Chen", 1000.00, 1);
        Classroom classRoom = new Classroom(1, 10);
        Book book = new Book("Harry Potter", 10);


        collection.add(student);
        collection.add(faculty);
        collection.add(classRoom);
        collection.add(book);
    }

    public void insert(Object obj){

        collection.add(obj);

    }

    public Student searchForStudent(int ID){
        for (Object obj: collection){
            if (obj instanceof Student && (Student)obj.getID() == ID){
                return (Student)obj;
            }
        }
    }

    public Faculty searchForFaculty(String name){
        for (Object obj : collection) {
            if (obj instanceof Faculty && (Faculty)obj.getName() == name) {
                return (Faculty)obj;
            }
        }
    }

    public Classroom searchForClass(int capacity){
        for (Object obj : collection) {
            if (obj instanceof Classroom && (Classroom)obj.getCapacity() == capacity) {
                return (Classroom)obj;
            }
        }
    }
    public Book searchForBook(int price){
        for (Object obj : collection) {
            if (obj instanceof Book && (Book) obj.getPrice() == price) {
                return (Book)obj;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Operator precedence, add parentheses. But also, that's not the right way to compare strings in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this code have a lot of problems.

1) The casting is not properly handled:

```
(Faculty) obj.getName() // not working
((Faculty) obj).getName() // this is the proper way of casting
```

2) Missing return statements in search methods. You should throw an exception or return something. I returned nulls in my example.

3) String comparison with `==` instead of `equals()`. String should always be compared with `equals()` if you want to compare if the strings are **equal** and not **identical**. The `==` compares the **identity** of the objects (non-primitive types) which returns true if they share the same memory address.

4) There is some design issues, it's better to keep each search method in related class rather than collect all of them under one. But I really don't know your purpose and task you want to solve, so let's concentrate on other issues.

There is the code where all compile-time issues fixed:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bag {

    private static ArrayList<Object> collection = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("Sameet", 1, 4);
        Faculty faculty = new Faculty("Chen", 1000.00, 1);
        Classroom classRoom = new Classroom(1, 10);
        Book book = new Book("Harry Potter", 10);


        collection.add(student);
        collection.add(faculty);
        collection.add(classRoom);
        collection.add(book);
    }

    public void insert(Object obj) {
        collection.add(obj);
    }

    public Student searchForStudent(int ID) {
        for (Object obj : collection) {
            if (obj instanceof Student && ((Student) obj).getId() == ID) {
                return (Student) obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Faculty searchForFaculty(String name) {
        for (Object obj : collection) {
            if (obj instanceof Faculty && name.equals(((Faculty) obj).getName())) {
                return (Faculty) obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Classroom searchForClass(int capacity) {
        for (Object obj : collection) {
            if (obj instanceof Classroom && ((Classroom) obj).getCapacity() == capacity) {
                return (Classroom) obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Book searchForBook(int price) {
        for (Object obj : collection) {
            if (obj instanceof Book && ((Book) obj).getPrice() == price) {
                return (Book) obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```